# How to change page orders using attributes in Jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I want to make a navigation bar with items in a priority order to make a link to pages. I added a attribute "priority" to pages. I wrote a code as follows to sort by the priority on layout HTMLs, but the pages aren't sorted. Why?

```
{% assign sorted_pages = site.pages | sort: "priority" %}
```

Layout HTMLs and pages are as follows:

**default.html**

```
  <nav class="main-nav">
    <div class="main-menu">
      <ul id="main-menu" class="menu">
        {% assign sorted_pages = site.pages | sort: "priority" %}
        {% for post in sorted_pages %}
            <li class="menu-item"><a class="menu-link" href="{{ post.permalink }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

**page1.md**

```
---
layout: page
title: "Page1"
priority: 0
permalink: "aaa/bbb/page1.html"
---

# Page1 #
...
```

**page2.md**

```
---
layout: page
title: "Page2"
priority: 1
permalink: "aaa/bbb/page2.html"
---

# Page2 #
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
{% assign sorted_pages = site.pages | sort: "priority" %}
{% for post in sorted_pages %}
    <li class="menu-item"><a class="menu-link" href="{{ post.permalink }}">
    {% if post.priority %}{{ post.priority }} - {% endif %}
    {{ post.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Then to see is order is reversed :

```
{% assign sorted_pages = site.pages | sort: "priority" | reverse %}
```